# IIS server port issue

Tags: port-forwarding, port, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I have server 2012 r2 set up trying to learn stuff.

Im trying to host website in IIS, problem i stumble upon is as following:

Website with all 3rd level names so www. dank. etc. works on local network as expected with bindings set to port 80 and local ip of the server. On router i opened port 80 but it spewed out error since 80 is in use by router its going to set 8080 instead (Tp-link TD-W8960N).

Is there a way to circumvent this? Can i use some random port for my site? I tried both forwarding 39000 and setting bindings to 39000 and i cant even open site locally. And when i check if ports are open it says closed.

Comment: Disable remote admin on your router. This should be done anyway as it is a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an other port than 80 in IIS you have to edit the bindings of your site and set to 39000. In standard environments the windows firewall is switched on, so you have to allow this port 39000 there. In some circumstances you then have to restart IIS services (`WAS` and `W3SVC`).

Then you should see a listening port 39000 running `netstat -ano | find "LISTEN"` from command line.